# The entity type 'AspNetUserLogins' requires a primary key to be defined?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, identity

He echo Scaffolding de la base de datos con EF y he cambiado midbcontext para que herede de IdentityDbContext porque quiero todo bajo un dbcontext. El problema es que al arrancar la aplicacion y introducir las credenciales en la pagina de Login recibo la excepcion: The entity type 'AspNetUserLogins' requires a primary key to be defined" y no se porque, ya que estoy llamando al metodo de la clase padre base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); Que estoy haciendo mal? Gracias.

```
public partial class AdventuresContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> 
{
    public AdventuresContext()
    {
    }

    public AdventuresContext(DbContextOptions<AdventuresContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Adventures> Adventures { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoleClaims> AspNetRoleClaims { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoles> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserClaims> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserLogins> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserRoles> AspNetUserRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserTokens> AspNetUserTokens { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUsers> AspNetUsers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Adventures");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "2.2.4-servicing-10062");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Adventures>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.UserId);

            entity.Property(e => e.CountryCodeIso03from).HasColumnName("CountryCodeISO03From");

            entity.Property(e => e.CountryCodeIso03to).HasColumnName("CountryCodeISO03To");

            entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasMaxLength(50);

            entity.Property(e => e.ShortDescription).HasMaxLength(128);

            entity.Property(e => e.Timestamp).IsRowVersion();

            entity.Property(e => e.UserId).IsRequired();

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
                .WithMany(p => p.Adventures)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Adventures_Adventures");
        });

        }
 }


 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Genre { get; set; }

    public DateTime Birth { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow in Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/). Official language in this site is spanish, so either translate your question, or redo it on [so]. Bienvenido a [es.so]. El idioma oficial de este sitio es el español, por lo que puede traducir su pregunta o rehacerla en [so].

Answer (score 1):

Hola yo tuve un problema similar en asp core 3 con las entidades y la verdad no se si te funcionara a ti en mi caso, se soluciono colocando a la entidad cual era la llave primaria de esta forma solo agregue [Key] de esta forma:

```
 namespace domain.Entities {
[Table("emp_sociedades_aux")]
public class sociedadesaux
{
    [Column("auxID")]
    [Key]
    public int auxID { get; set; }

    [Column("sociedadID")]
    public int sociedadID { get; set; }

    [Column("proveedorID")]
    public int proveedorID { get; set; }
}}
```

De ahí todo funciono genial espero te sirva